# How to customize search functionality in salesforce community?

Tags: community, customer-community, search, global-search

My requirement is to display cases of only specific record type in search results on customer community. How can that search result be customized for this requirement.

Comment: Are they allowed to view any cases of the other record types?  If not, then criteria-based sharing rules would be my first choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear as to what approach you are looking for,

Therefore, here are several approaches:

you can use permission sets to grant what record types your community users have access to, that way, when they search, cases of record type x would show up, you can achieve something similar by setting what record types a user has access to at a profile level.

Otherwise, you can create your custom component to filter by record type in the results since the Global Search Result and Search Result components do not allow you to preset filters other than the object type.

for further information on implementing at a profile level or through premission set, you can check review this documentation:

[How is record type access specified](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/permissions_record_type_access.htm)

Comment: Beware that permission sets are less restrictive than profiles; they are meant to open permissions, not restrict them, so if the profile has access to all record types, a restrictive permission set will do nothing :S

Comment: nonetheless, there are several approaches on how to implement the users requirement. It all depends how he manages security within his org, so th option is out there.

Comment: My comment was more for the "_you can set permission sets to *restrict* what record types..._" . He has to use permission sets to *open / grant* access to them

Comment: Ooops =P , indeed, I will change my wording. Thanks, Gracias!